# How to locate a phone without user knowing

Tags: settings, geolocation, parental-control

I have a daughter that goes to a secondary school and has a S5 phone. I want to be able to locate her without her knowing, as in receiving any pop ups or notifications. Can you help me please?

Comment: It's not exactly anyone's place to tell you what to do, but I'm going to throw my two cents in; this is the one surefire way to ruin any kind of trust relationship you could have with your daughter. Maybe, instead of tracking her, you communicate with her and respect her privacy?

Answer (score 3):

I think the best option is to tell her you are going to track her. She will find out, unless you deploy some borderline illegal methods.

Life360 is a few app. It will notify you where she is. No pop ups on her phone.

Don't be a prick and spy on your kid. Just be honest if you want you kid to respect you.

Answer (score 0):

The best thing you can do is get her Google password whichever account is active for that device and use Google device manger for the same. But she will be aware because whenever we locate device popup will be shown on her phone, well we can disable notifications for Google Play Services and she won't get the popup. This way you can get her location with existing methods.

Cons using this method :

1. GPS and Internet should remain active
2. Getting her password is hassle

Answer (score 0):

While I'm completely agree with the rest of the answers, You CAN use carbonite app which can locate the device without showing any UI.

There are multiple apps on play store which can do the same. Or if you're capable, you can even install your own app.

Having said that, as @Rthomas529 noted, this will ruin any trust your daughter has on you irreversibly. And frankly, she is entitled to her privacy. Most apps on play store for this type of function are designed for theft prevention rather than invading privacy. If this is noted by any authorities, you may be looking at legal prosecution depending on the law where you live and your daughter's age.

You can also simply ask her permission and install Google Device Manager (which does pop a notification when remotely located).

**I VERY STRONGLY suggest you reconsider your options.**

Answer (score -3):

When she Gets Home, Go on her Phone and Go to settings, about Phone, More info and write down her Phones *IP ADRESS*

Then when she is out, go to   IP Tracker, type her IP address in and lookup where she is on the map..

Hope it helps!

Comment: You know that this will display the WiFi IP address, in case the device is connected to WiFi. Also this IP changes from cell tower to cell tower.

Comment: Also: IP addresses can be as accurate as 2 miles or as inaccurate as half a country.